# Does Java support double-width CAS?

Tags: java, atomic, compare-and-swap, double-compare-and-swap

Is there a way to perform a double-width (16-byte) compare-and-swap in Java if the hardware supports it (e.g. using CMPXCHG16B on Intel)?

Comment: You would have to use a library with a native implementation.

Answer (score 0):

No.

There is no instruction in the Java Byte code specification that covers that. And there is also nothing in the Java Language specification to work around "deficiency".

So, theoretically, a JVM *implementation* might compile certain Java byte code sequences in order to use such hardware based instructions. But as said: that would be implementation specific.